# Linking error using xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker

**Hey guys i'm try to build my app but it didn't just stoped when linking ? strange error here is the log**

Ld /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.app/SearchPRO normal i386
    cd /Users/alyjamy/Downloads/SearchPRO
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchPRO.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -lxml2 -lz -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.app/SearchPRO

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Google_SearchView.refParentViewController in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Google_SearchView-F440D65BB38D9558.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Google_SearchView-41A2B8A23D2A1652.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Google_SearchView in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Google_SearchView-F440D65BB38D9558.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Google_SearchView-41A2B8A23D2A1652.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Google_SearchView in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Google_SearchView-F440D65BB38D9558.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Google_SearchView-41A2B8A23D2A1652.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_HomeView.refParentViewController in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/HomeView-5DC4F3DA47F5C55B.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/HomeView-B126BFA53128822A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_HomeView in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/HomeView-5DC4F3DA47F5C55B.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/HomeView-B126BFA53128822A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_HomeView in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/HomeView-5DC4F3DA47F5C55B.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/HomeView-B126BFA53128822A.o
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-90B20DF7C3920B56.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_iSearchProAppDelegate.navigationController in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/iSearchProAppDelegate-FC941BF9786A1D61.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/iSearchProAppDelegate-5039F6A504D7A3A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_iSearchProAppDelegate.window in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/iSearchProAppDelegate-FC941BF9786A1D61.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/iSearchProAppDelegate-5039F6A504D7A3A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_iSearchProAppDelegate in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/iSearchProAppDelegate-FC941BF9786A1D61.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/iSearchProAppDelegate-5039F6A504D7A3A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_iSearchProAppDelegate in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/iSearchProAppDelegate-FC941BF9786A1D61.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/iSearchProAppDelegate-5039F6A504D7A3A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Twitter_SearchView.refParentViewController in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchView-3920747535A2AD6A.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchView-F6065DBEB33D9A3C.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Twitter_SearchView in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchView-3920747535A2AD6A.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchView-F6065DBEB33D9A3C.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Twitter_SearchView in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchView-3920747535A2AD6A.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchView-F6065DBEB33D9A3C.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Twitter_SearchViewController in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchViewController-2A2332C99892CD6C.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchViewController-E7091C13162DBA3E.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Twitter_SearchViewController in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchViewController-2A2332C99892CD6C.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Twitter_SearchViewController-E7091C13162DBA3E.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Youtube_SearchView.refParentViewController in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchView-1B25F11DFB82ED6E.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchView-FE4CD6F8B0DC7B2A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Youtube_SearchView in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchView-1B25F11DFB82ED6E.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchView-FE4CD6F8B0DC7B2A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Youtube_SearchView in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchView-1B25F11DFB82ED6E.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchView-FE4CD6F8B0DC7B2A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Youtube_SearchViewController in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchViewController-3269AC039631AE5A.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchViewController-EF4F954D13CC9B2C.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Youtube_SearchViewController in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchViewController-3269AC039631AE5A.o
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Youtube_SearchViewController-EF4F954D13CC9B2C.o
ld: 21 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**can you help me with**

**solved this error when i removed the duplicate now i have it**

Ld /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.app/SearchPRO normal i386
    cd /Users/alyjamy/Downloads/SearchPRO
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SearchPRO.LinkFileList -Xlinker --no-demangle -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -lxml2 -lz -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.app/SearchPRO

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-AC1E3FF737776656.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**??**

Comment: Can you post your code? the place where the error happens

Comment: Just paste the error code.....

Answer (score 2):

Your `Youtube_SearchViewController.m` and other `Youtube_SearchView.m` files are listed twice in your "Compile Sources" build phase.

Select your project in the Project Navigator on the left, then select your target in the list of targets, go to the "Build Phases" tab, and remove every duplicate files (so that each .m file is only listed once).

---

Details on how to interpret the build log *(emphasis added and reformatted)*:

> **duplicate symbol** _OBJC_IVAR_$_**Google_SearchView.refParentViewController** in:
>
> - /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/**Google_SearchView-F440D65BB38D9558.o**
> - /Users/alyjamy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SearchPRO-byuygadvkgrdzqgiethjtvoscvzp/Build/Intermediates/SearchPRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchPRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/**Google_SearchView-41A2B8A23D2A1652.o**

In the extract above, the `Google_searchView.m` is compiled twice, producing both `Google_SearchView-F440D65BB38D9558.o` and `Google_SearchView-41A2B8A23D2A1652.o`

Comment: delete them cool now havaing other error gonna edit the subject now

Comment: You still have the main() function duplicated, probably the `main.m` file still present twice (or the `main()` function defined at two different places in your code maybe)

Comment: yeah great mmmm thanks, after i solved it i faced what i'm gonna write above

Comment: Then maybe you could vote/accept the solutions I gave you?!